# jQuery - Get active class from one list item and set this class to another list

Tags: jquery, html

I have two lists with 5 items

First:

```
<ol class="controls">
    <li><a id="bullet-0">1</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" id="bullet-1">2</a></li>
    <li><a id="bullet-2">3</a></li>
    <li><a id="bullet-3">4</a></li>
    <li><a id="bullet-4">5</a></li>
</ol>
```

Second:

```
<ul class="years">
    <li id="to-1973" class="year">1973</li>
    <li id="to-1983" class="year">1983</li>
    <li id="to-1994" class="year">1994</li>
    <li id="to-2004" class="year">2004</li>
    <li id="to-2015" class="year">2015</li>
</ul>
```

I want to check with jQuery if hasClass '***active***' from first list, and then set this class to second list.
For example: 
If second item from first list has class ***active***, set this class ***active*** to second item from second list and then etc. If third item from first list is ***active*** then remove active from second list and set it to third item.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Are you still struggling for the solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems most of the answers are targeting the list-item instead of the anchor (which has the active class).

```
//get the index of the active control (target anchor, then get index of parent li)
var index = $('.controls a.active').parent().index();
//remove the current active from the years
$('.years li.active').removeClass('active');
//assign active to correct year
$('.years li').eq(index).addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **.eq()**  and **.index()**

```
$('.years > li').eq($('.controls > li > a.active').closest('li').index()).addClass('active');
```

get the li index from the 1st list and then addClass to the same li index in the 2nd list

if you need to use it in click event

```
$('.controls > li > a').on('click', function(){
   var ThisIt = $(this);
   $('.years > li').eq(ThisIt.closest('li').index()).addClass('active');
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/Lb7sg7m0/1/)

> Note: don't forget to include jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```js
$('.controls > li').on('click', function() {
  $('.active').removeClass('active'); // first remove the active class
  $('a', this).addClass('active'); // now add the active class
  $('.years > li').eq($('.controls .active').parent().index()).addClass('active');
  // here you can add the active class to specific list item.
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
First:

<ol class="controls">
  <li><a id="bullet-0">1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="bullet-1">2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="bullet-2">3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="bullet-3">4</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="bullet-4">5</a>
  </li>
</ol>
Second:

<ul class="years">
  <li id="to-1973" class="year">1973</li>
  <li id="to-1983" class="year">1983</li>
  <li id="to-1994" class="year">1994</li>
  <li id="to-2004" class="year">2004</li>
  <li id="to-2015" class="year">2015</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
var cache = $("ol.controls a");
$("ul.years li").eq(cache.index(cache.filter(".active")).addClass("active");
```